# validator for characters exceeding size of a text box

Tags: java, validation, jsf

I have a table one of whose column is varchar(64). I am building a web form in Java using JSF where the form has a text box where the users type in free text and is saved to the column in the above mentioned table. I need to write a validator to check if the number of characters in the text box exceeds 64 (as it will crash when saved to the database). Need some suggestions to write this validator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{user.username}" 
                size="64" required="true"
                label="UserName" >
                <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="64" />
            </h:inputText>
```

- [Reference](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-validatelength-example/)

Comment: @mona you are always welcome to upvote/ mark it as answer as it is for your , you are welcome btw :)